# Do you need to run own server when using a full node wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, electrum, wallet-security

Hi can you help out pls:

1) There are some full node wallets like Bitcoin Core or Wasabi. What other full node wallet apps are available to select from for bitcoin?

2) I have read about people using ledger+electrum+electrum server  to run a full node. Is it mandatory to have an own server when using a full node wallet like the ones mentioned in 1)?

3) If there is no need for an own server: What pros/cons are there in terms of wallet security, using own electrum server  vs.  not having own server?

Thanks

Comment: For the record today Wasabi could not finish its full node integration yet. The validation (most important) part is still missing. Regarding the current status, we're trying to add a feature to Bitcoin Core that'd make our job easier: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/18223

Comment: As far as I know Wasabi is a light client as Electrum is and connecting the former to your own full node, while beneficial for your privacy, is optional. More: https://docs.wasabiwallet.io/using-wasabi/BitcoinFullNode.html#the-importance-of-running-a-full-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What other full node wallet apps are available to select from for bitcoin?**

See https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet for a reasonable list

> **Is it mandatory to have an own server when using a full node wallet**

Not really. Some wallets have an API that allows other software to interact with the wallet but the wallets are generally usable directly for straightforward use.

> **What pros/cons are there in terms of wallet security**

Security is a complicated subject. On the one hand you want to keep things simple to minimise the exposed attack surface. On the other hand you may want to support coin mixing or other strategies to improve privacy. Unless you have some specific security requirements, the general advice is to keep the private keys under your exclusive control on a computer that is well protected. Use a hardware wallet for larger amounts or infrequently accessed Bitcoin.

Comment: thx @RedGrittyBrick ! i saw your link, but there is just bitcoincore as a full node wallet listed. Isnt there another fullnode GUI wallet available currently? I want one which can interact with Ledger

Comment: @johnsmiththelird Bitcoin Core supports hardware wallets (including Ledger) through the HWI branch added since v0.18